# How do I use a Perl CGI locally without using curl and apache2?

Tags: perl, apache, curl, cgi

I would like to submit a form to a CGI script localy (w3c-markup-validator), but it is too slow using `curl` and `apache`, I want to use this CGI script more than 5,000 times in an another script.
and currently it takes more than one hour.

What should I do to give the form directly to the CGI script (I upload a file with `curl`)?

edit: It seems to be too complicated and time consuming for what I needed, so I waited 1 hour and a half, each time I needed to test my generated xhtml files.
In definitive I didn't test any of the answers below, so the question will remain open.

Comment: With cUrl you can specify any addess to upload file? Or I'm missing something?

Comment: Is the CGI script you are invoking under your control, or are you actually initiating a DOS attack on a web site?

Comment: it's under my control, cause it's in my /usr/lib/cgi-bin it's the w3c-markup-validator and I want to validate a batch of xhtml file 6537 exactly.

Comment: @Ivan I think you are. @Sinan I'm currently reading your post about the css validator, thanks.

Comment: Argh! I spoke too soon. I was fooled by the clean cut modularity of the CSS validator.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the details of the script you might be able to create a fake CGI environment using [HTTP::Request::AsCGI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTTP::Request::AsCGI) and then sourcing the CGI script with the "do" operator. But when it comes to speed and maintainability your best bet would be to factor the important part of the script's work into its own module, and rewrite the CGI as a client of that module. That way you don't *have* to invoke it as a CGI -- the batch job you're talking about now would be just another program using the same module to do the same work, but without CGI or the webserver environment getting in the way.

Comment: thanks for your help! I'll try HTTP:Request::AsCGI; it's not my script it's w3c-markup-validator check perl script; and I didn't find any module for doing so. and since I'm not a perl guru I don't think I'll will refactor w3c work.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I looked at the source code for this thing and it is not easy extract the validation stuff from all the rest. So, here is what I would.

First, ditch `curl`. Starting a new process for each file you want to validate is not a good idea. You are going to need to write a driver script that takes a list of URL's and submits them to your local server running on `localhost`. In fact, you might later want to parallelize this because there will normally be a bunch of `httpd` processes alive anyway. Well, I get ahead of myself.

This script can use [LWP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/LWP) because all you are doing is submitting some data to the CGI script on `localhost` and storing/processing results. You do not need full [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/WWW::Mechanize) functionality.

As for the `validator` CGI script, you should configure that as a [mod_perl registry script](http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/api/ModPerl/Registry.html). Make sure you preload all necessary libraries.

This should boost documents processed per second from 1.3 to something more palatable.

Comment: I was using curl like that: curl -F output=soap12 -F "uploaded_file=@/path;type=text/html" http://localhost/w3c-markup-validator/check; and you're right it was not a good idea. how the driver script is working? I'll give all the file to curl with LWP?
Thansk!

Comment: You submit the file and any other options to the CGI script using LWP. There is no need for `curl`. Of course, you could use `libcurl` as well. See http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/WWW::Curl

Answer (score 1):

CGI is a pretty simple API. All it does is read data either from an environment variable (for GET requests) or from stdin (for POST requests). So all you need is to do is to set up the environment and call the script. See the [docs for details](http://hoohoo.ncsa.illinois.edu/cgi/forms.html).

Comment: It's not as simple as you seem to think it is. In the case of file upload you would also need to set up the mime encodings. It doesn't just read the file directly from STDIN.

Comment: thanks for the advice, if I didn't suceed trying all your answer, I'll maybe use tidy.

Comment: +1 You're right; you must property encode the file. But that's not too hard, either: The mime header is pretty much static, the length comes from an environment variable, so all that's left is the encoding of the data.

Comment: ps: I will not use tidy.. it doesn't validate as well as w3c-markup-validator

Answer (score 0):

If the script uses CGI.pm, you can run it from the command line by supplying the '-debug' switch (to CGI.pm, in the use statement.) That will then allow you to send the post variables on stdin. You may have to tweak the script a little to make this work.