# Argument List Too Long - cgi (Perl)

Tags: perl

I running a cgi file using Linux command. It give me this error below:

```
./file.cgi : Argument List Too Long.
```

I just copy existing content from existing cgi file which is running ok to a new created .cgi file and running it. And it gives me the error as stated above.

Comment: BTW, Why would you want run a CGI script from the command line? They're meant to be handled by the web server. If you stil want to use a CGI script that way, perhaps for testing or automation, then see this post for some ideas:                http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701934/how-do-i-use-a-perl-cgi-locally-without-using-curl-and-apache2

Comment: @GeneQ: I open it in browser it show 'Internal Server Error', so I try to run it using Linux command, test it to see whether it would show out the script inside the cgi file or not, thus it give me this error.

Comment: @All: oh...I create new file and copy the content of existing file, it gives me this error. While I copy whole existing file and rename it, it not give me this error. Anybody know why does this happened?

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of this issue is probably more to do with how to use the Linux command line properly than about Perl. Can't help you more with so little details.

Here's the long and short of it from the Linux Journal : ["Argument list too long": Beyond Arguments and Limitations](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6060)